# How can I lock images in Google Sheets so they can appear on the same positions despite different screen resolutions?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I'm doing a floor map template for my company, so they can easily update it every time each team is assigned to different desks.

For this, I resized all cells with the same height and weight values so they could all be perfect squares, and then I placed a png with the map floor above the cells.

When I need to assign or update the owner of a desk, since I can't click on the cell through the png, I click outside the png and then use the arrow keys to go and change whatever I want.

However, there is something that I noticed and it's bugging me.
When someone else accesses the link (even if they don't have permission to edit), the png with the map floor covering all cells doesn't appear precisely where it should be.

I noticed that this changes from computer to computer (different screen resolutions) or even when I zoom in or out on either the Google Sheet option or the browser zoom option.

I want to know if there's some hidden option for imported images or some other way to prevent this, so the presentation can be the same despite the screen resolution or zoom each person uses on their computer.

Thanks in advance.